# Difference between onsubmit="return false" and onsubmit="javascript:return false"

Tags: javascript

What is the diference between

```
onsubmit="javascript:return false"
```

and

```
onsubmit="return false"
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first example starts with a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) (to which a `break` or `continue` statement could be linked). This is pointless as there is no loop in the function to apply the label to and no `break` or `continue` statement.

It is probably there due to cargo culting from people who are copy/pasting `javascript:` scheme URIs from `href` attributes.

---

Consider making your JavaScript [Unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and [binding your event handlers with JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead of HTML.